# OpenCL Compatibility Discrepancy

Tags: macos, opencl, compatibility

So I ran the code found in [How can i test for OpenCL compability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892955/how-can-i-test-for-opencl-compability)
for an iMac (Late 2012) 
and I got the following result:

> Device Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz supports OpenCL 1.2
>   Device GeForce GTX 675MX supports OpenCL 1.1

Does this mean that in order for me to run code utilizing CPU *and* GPU at once, I will have to use OpenCL 1.1? What if I want to code using OpenCL 1.2 specification? Will that mean that the code will only utilize the CPU?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is mostly correct.  You will have to ensure that functions you use are part of **both** OpenCL 1.1 and 1.2, i.e. functions that have been deprecated in 1.2 should be avoided since there is no guarantee that they will be provided on OpenCL 1.2 devices.  Looking at the pretty short list of deprecated features, I don't think that this will be a significant problem.

If you absolutely have to use an OpenCL 1.2 feature then you will have to use your CPU and forget the GPU.  However, I have yet to find anything in the 1.2 standard that has forced me to do this.

Just a warning, if you use any libraries that use OpenCL, make sure which version they target or if they have code to switch between the two.  Using functions from 1.2 on your Nvidia GPU will cause a segfault.

Comment: One more question, @chippies: Does the result mean that the OpenCL 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2 SDKs are all installed in this particular iMac? I ask because I am interested in using OpenCL 1.1 to program GPU and CPU concurrently.

Comment: The results you posted above make no mention about OpenCL 1.0, so there is no device that guarantees support for that version.  As for v1.1 and v1.2, my limited understanding of Macs is that there is one OpenCL platform, hence there is only one OpenCL SDK which exposes both v1.1 and v1.2 features.  To run identical code on both devices, you will have to stick to the set of OpenCL 1.1 features that have not been deprecated in 1.2.