# Use OpenCL at Mac with xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, opencl

I have done some CUDA programming at Windows and now I want to learn OpenCL. I have Macbook retina which contains `Intel Iris` graphics card. I already have `xCode`. I tried to find a lot at internet about how can I check if OpenCL is already installed at my Mac but I could not understand a proper way. I just read that Macbook will automatically get OpenCL installed with xCode.

I wrote few lines which are related to OpenCL but it throws error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_clGetPlatformIDs", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am completely new to OpenCL and unable to understand how things work with OpenCL.

**My Code:**

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include "OpenCL/opencl.h"
#else
#include "CL/cl.h"
#endif

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cl_uint platformIdCount = 0;
    clGetPlatformIDs (0, nullptr, &platformIdCount);

    cout<<"Test openCL";
    return 0;
}
```

**PS:** Inclusion of header files does not throw any error. The error occurs due to `clGetPlatformIDs()` in the `main()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to link against the OpenCL framework. This involves adding `-framework OpenCL` to your command-line, or if you're using Xcode adding `OpenCL.framework` to the **Link Binary With Libraries** section in **Build Phases**.

Comment: with your suggestion, there is no error for the code which I mentioned in my post but the sample code at SO ( `http://stackoverflow.com/a/7898347/2386113` ) is still throwing an error for `cl_device_id* devices = calloc(sizeof(cl_device_id), num_devices);`. The error say: `Cannot initialize a variable of type cl_device_id`

Comment: If you read the whole error message, it will tell you that you are assigning a `void*` to a `cl_device_id*`. Just cast the result of the `calloc` call to a `cl_device_id*`.